# How to implement an identical POST like the regular PUT in an odata controller to update an entity

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, odata

Given the following typical implementation of an ODataController's [PUT method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint#update-an-entity), how would I make the exact same method ALSO be available as a POST?

I am developing an OData end-point that will be called from an external system that I have no control over. It appears that that system implements the Update semantics (to tell my system to update an entity) wrongly by sending a POST with a uri key instead of using a PUT.

```cs
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, Product update)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    if (key != update.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    db.Entry(update).State = EntityState.Modified;
    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ProductExists(key))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    return Updated(update);
}
```

My first guess was to annotate the method with [AcceptVerbs("PUT", "POST")] to make the same exact method implementation be available as a POST, but that doesn't work.  It's probably that the ODataConventionModelBuilder default setup doesn't know about this...

Ideally I'd like to keep the standards based PUT and the regular POST for inserts, but add a special post that is identical to the put but differs only in the verb.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding some not so evident [documentation on salesforce.com](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=odata_considerations_writable_external_objects.htm&type=5) on odata endpoint implementation for External Data Source/External Objects, it became evident to me that salesforce.com tries to call a POST for Update semantics on the external object but also adds the X-HTTP-METHOD set as PATCH.

So, the solution was to implement the following class:

```cs
   public class MethodOverrideHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        readonly string[] _methods = { "DELETE", "HEAD", "PUT", "PATCH", "MERGE" };
        const string _header1 = "X-HTTP-Method-Override";
        const string _header2 = "X-HTTP-Method";//salesforce special behavior???

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
            HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // Check for HTTP POST with the X-HTTP-Method-Override header.
            if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.Headers.Contains(_header1))
            {
                // Check if the header value is in our methods list.
                var method = request.Headers.GetValues(_header1).FirstOrDefault();
                if (_methods.Contains(method, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // Change the request method.
                    request.Method = new HttpMethod(method);
                }
            }
            else  if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.Headers.Contains(_header2))
            {
                // Check if the header value is in our methods list.
                var method = request.Headers.GetValues(_header2).FirstOrDefault();
                if (_methods.Contains(method, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // Change the request method.
                    request.Method = new HttpMethod(method);
                }
            }
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

and register it in `WebApiConfig.Register(HttpConfiguration config)` as such:

```cs
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new MethodOverrideHandler());
```

Now, the non-odata compliant POST for salesforce update operations on the External Object will get delegated to the standards compliant odata implementation (in the ODataController) of PUT method I originally posted.

I hope that this helps someone in the future...

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to throw some more logic into the method to check and see if a record already exists in the database using `update.Id` then checking whether or not the data is null.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, Product update)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    //might have to get rid of this condition for the sake of new entries
    //if (key != update.Id)
    //{
        //return BadRequest();
    //}

    try
    {
        //not sure what the name of your table is so I'm going to call it ProductTable
        var foo = db.ProductTable.Where(p => p.Id == update.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if(foo == null)
        {
            db.Entry(update).State = EntityState.Added;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(update).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Updated(update);
        }
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        if (!ProductExists(key))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
       {
            throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException(ex.Message);
       }
    }
}
```

***EDIT***
Just noticed the ProductExists method... I would take that out of the catch block and throw it into the try

```
//for Post, pass in a 0 for key's argument
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, Product update)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    //might have to get rid of this condition for the sake of new entries
    //if (key != update.Id)
    //{
        //return BadRequest();
    //}

    try
    {
        if (!ProductExists(key))
        {
            db.Entry(update).State = EntityState.Added;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        }
        else
        {
            db.Entry(update).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Updated(update);
        }
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        throw new DbUpdateConcurrencyException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I appreciate your response but I think you misunderstood my question, it was more about how to delegate a POST (with a PUT odata signature) to the actual PUT implementation.  But I also found out more about the issue and answered my own question.

Comment: Ah, sorry haha. I'm glad you found the solution though!